# Javascript .toUpperCase()

Tags: javascript, prompt

sorry for my English.
I have this code:

```
x = 0
y=prompt("Whats your name?");
if (x == "andrea")
{
x=x+1
}
.....
document.write("You made "+ x +" points.");
```

How can i make the prompt's answer uppercase?
Thanks.

Not the document.write but the answer, for example, "andrea".
I want that when the user write the answer , for example "andrea" it is uppercase.

**I want that the user is forced to write the answer uppercase.**

Comment: Um..? Use google and learn Javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Comment: you have the answer in your questions title what isn't working?

Comment: @chrismborland w3schools is a terrible resource. Please use MDN instead

Comment: Your code will never work, because you're comparing `x` to `"andrea"`, where `x` is `0`, so the `if` statement will never pass. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it's the better alternative to `document.write`: http://jsfiddle.net/vr37Y/1/

Comment: @JanDvorak - Fair enough.  Will do in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: you can't force the user to write a promt text in uppercase, however you can convert it to uppercase later.

Comment: @cocco you could reask until the user response is uppercase

Comment: @Jan Dvorak - Even though w3schools has its flaws, MDN is neither as intuitive nor as helpful as w3schools for beginners. It is good for a primary resource, albeit based on the assumption that the user pretty much has a grasp of the subject. In short, explanations rely on multiple terms that are not understood by the beginner.

Answer (score 2):

toUpperCase & toLowerCase() example

```
var x=0;
var y=prompt("Come ti chiami?");
if(y.toLowerCase()=="andrea"){
 x++;
}

document.write(y.toUpperCase()+", hai fatto "+ x +" punti");
```

append alternative

```
var answer=y.toUpperCase‌​()+", hai fatto "+ x +" punti"
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerText=answer;
```

Comment: Can you suggest something else instead of `document.write`?

Comment: depends what you wanna do?

Comment: most likely the desired action is to reply to the user. `document.write` doesn't work after the page load, however.

Comment: I want that when the user write the answer , for example "andrea" it is uppercase.

Comment: document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerText=y.toUpperCase()+", hai fatto "+ x +" punti";

Comment: @JanDvorak: Why are you filling comments with an off-topic holy war against `document.write`? Here again, it's not the topic at hand, and is likely being used correctly. You seem to be on a mission to expunge all mentions of this tool from the internet. Is there a particular reason for this obsession?

Comment: @CrazyTrain once again - `document.write` shouldn't be taught because in 99.99% cases it cannot be used and in 90% of the rest it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's not being taught in any manner in this question, nor in the previous where we had this discussion. Again, why this obsession that causes you to leave a myriad of off-topic comments?

Comment: @CrazyTrain once again - being present in an answer ~~ being taught

Comment: These are not offtopic comments. They relate to the post they are under. "What a beautiful weather is it" would be off-topic.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, you can't teach someone what they already know. By using your user name in this comment, am I teaching you what your user name is?

Comment: Yes, they're off the topic of what is being asked. Please stop this obsession and your spread of FUD.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Sorry for butting in for the second day in a row, but if an answer contained an improper use of `eval`, would you allow it and upvote it?

Comment: @CrazyTrain By using my name you show them you believe I should be talked to :-)

Comment: @Ian: If it was introduced by the answer and was improper, I would point it out, as it would be part of the solution. This use of `document.write` is neither introduced in the answer, nor is there any indication that it's improper.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in the [javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Comment: @CrazyTrain I agree about introducing it, but it doesn't mean it should be encouraged either. Just because the OP is using something improperly doesn't mean your answer should encourage it. For example, if the OP was making a calculator and used `eval` like `eval(firstOperand + operation secondOperand);` and asked why it didn't work, there shouldn't be an answer that says "Well, you forgot to use `+` to add the `secondOperand`". The simple fact that `document.write` is continued to be used (without any warning) means that it encourages people to use it, where 99% of the time you shouldn't be

Comment: @Ian: There's no indication that it's being used improperly. And again, if OP does use it improperly, it'll become immediately obvious. Simply answering a question and including a tool that OP decided to use, doesn't mean it's being encouraged. And to give such blanket discouragements is to spread FUD. What should be done is to help people understand the tools they use. Something like `document.write` should be used 100% of the time where a knowledgeable developer has decided to use it. The key is to produce knowledgeable developers, not paranoid ones.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I still don't see why you should encourage it. Sure, the OP doesn't make it clear where/how the code is being used, so we can't determine if the document is closed or not. Giving blind encouragements is a bad idea. At least with detailed discouragements, the OP and other readers are informed. Again, without some warning/explanation, suggesting the continued use of `document.write` only gives the wrong idea for everyone. People won't bother checking if `document.write` is used in the OP in the right context (before document is closed) and they'll think it's okay to use everywhere.

Comment: @Ian: Why do I have to say this again? Simply answering a question and including a tool that OP decided to use, doesn't mean it's being encouraged. Encouragement would be to tell the OP to use `document.write` as often as possible. And *once again*, the first time OP uses `document.write` improperly, it'll be very clear. It's not like something that introduces subtle bugs that are not easily detectable. You seem to be wanting to solve all potential problems OP could possibly encounter by creating blanket rules. That's not good practice for a developer.

Comment: @CrazyTrain You have to say it again because it doesn't make sense. Using the same tool is encouraging, sorry. You're right, as soon as they use it improperly, **they'll know**. But why let people think it's okay to use blindly? They'll end up using it improperly, being confused, and coming here to ask a question that has probably been duplicated several times. I don't see why suggesting `document.write` alternatives is the same as "wanting to solve all potential problems". Do you not want to help the OP and other readers? If it's possible to suggest better practices, shouldn't you?

Comment: @CrazyTrain (cont.) JanDvorak wasn't saying "this answer is wrong because you use `document.write`"; he was just asking for an alternative for the OP's sake. If the answerer explained something as simple as "`document.write` should only be used before the document is closed, otherwise you can look into _____ (or here is some code)", that would be great. I don't see why trying to cover any possible problems the OP could encounter with the code provided. I see these suggestions all the time over SO, so why aren't you commenting on them and saying it's unnecessary to suggest a better practice?

Comment: @Ian: No, that's not what encouragement is. You're assuming OP is using it blindly. You're assuming OP won't search for the answer if it's used improperly. I never said that "suggesting alternatives" is wanting to solve all potential problems. I was only reacting to Jan's blanket prohibition. You seem to have created a reality that doesn't exist. Yes, I want to help people, and making a blanket prohibition against `document.write` is terribly *unhelpful*. You're trying to change this discussion to make it sound like I'm against any sort of suggestion.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Sorry, I just find it more helpful to explain potential problems. People use `.onclick =` when it could easily be suggested to use `addEventListener` with a link that explains why. Someone may or may not understand why assigning `onclick` twice doesn't work, but it could be avoided if they used `addEventListener` in the first place.

Comment: i like that there is a .onclick in some cases ... because when i wanna change it's function a new .onclick simply overwrites it. Else i need to use removeEventListener (and that has various problems especially on older browsers.).

Comment: @CrazyTrain Providing an answer that uses something means it's encouraged. There's a good chance the OP accepts it, and then thousands of others see the question/answer...I'd say that's "encouragement". I'm assuming they're using it blindly because I've never seen a practical use for it, I never see other people actually using it (except for very specific reasons), and I don't see popular libraries using it...and I can't see a good reason to use it when other methods can be used that work everywhere. I agree prohibition isn't a good idea, but *warning*/*explaining* isn't such a bad idea.

Comment: @cocco Very true, but using the `listener` stuff allows you to actually manage your **own** stuff without modifying other use. As soon as you start incorporating others' code, setting `onclick` *may* conflict. It absolutely depends on the situation, just like `document.write` and `eval`, but that's why it's good to explain differences or provide a link that does so.

Comment: your right.. talking about my personal experience... i also don't use other libraries... i write my own code everytime.. i like coding.

Comment: @Ian: Coding practices should *never* be based on FUD. Responsible developers understand tools, and then choose when to use them. Blanket prohibitions are rarely helpful. Also, your code example under the question used `window.onload = func...`.

Comment: (new Function('functionhere'))() is a good alternative to eval.It cannot access local variables because the code runs in a separate scope

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'm not saying they're based on FUD...they should provide a explanation for each method. At the same time, when there's such a high chance that something shouldn't be used, I don't see why suggesting other is a bad idea. Responsible developers, yes, but how many of those visit this site? Too many are aspiring/learning developers that learn their ways here. Again, I'm not for prohibition, I'm for explanations. And very funny - I know it used `window.onload`, but it was in a comment :) And I know several of my answers on SO use `onload` and stuff, but I wasn't always in this mindset

Comment: @Ian: I'm saying much of the advice being given here is based on FUD. And I'm all for suggestions. My original comment is dealing with Jan going around and asking *(or sometimes telling)* people to remove `document.write` from their answers. Fact is that there are times where it's desired to generate content while the page is loading. If that's what OP wants to do, then that's what OP should do.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Absolutely, it can be great for generating content! Not to be a pain, but even in that scenario, I'd still suggest using `createElement`, `document.appendChild`, and stuff like that, but I won't get into that, and they're welcome to use either way anyways. You're right though, your original comments (and comments since then) haven't exactly been going against what I'm saying, I think we're just saying it differently; suggestions, explanations and warnings are better than prohibition

Comment: @Ian: Yep, I like the DOM methods, and that's the approach I'd normally take. Just not willing to throw any tool out of the box. :-) But yes, information is always good.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Great way to put it :) And thanks for talking through all this, although it probably seems silly looking back on it

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
y=prompt("Whats your name?");
if (y == "andrea")
```

Instead of

```
y=prompt("Whats your name?");
if (x == "andrea")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(("Hai fatto "+ x +" punti").toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to uppercase the whole text, only `x`.

Comment: Sorry, not the document.write but the answer, for example, "andrea".

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
var lowerText="Hai fatto "+ x +" punti";
document.write(lowerText.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Sorry, not the document.write but the answer, for example, "andrea".

Comment: I don't think he wants to uppercase the whole text, only `x`.